# Cassandra - Unique UserID across cluster

Tags: cassandra

Currently i test some Database-systems(NoSql), and now i test something with Cassandra. There isn't a option for Auto-increment a for example userID like in MySQL. Now is the question, how i can generate UUIDs across a complete cluster? Facebook used Cassandra in history, too, and they generate a userID, too(https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me). How did they make this?

Answer (score 3):

You should use one of the UUID types - UUIDType or TimeUUIDType.  Use TimeUUIDType if you want to be able to order your IDs by time.  Wrap it in ReversedType if you want to get the newest first, rather than the oldest first.

Answer (score 1):

a unique id is just a combination of the computer mac(or you could use hostname) plus a unique id on that machine (across restarts of the server).  PlayOrm for cassandra actually generates short ids with that in mind using the system.currenttimemillions though with additions to make it unique when necessary.  The TimeUUID type is mac + time (plus some addition to time to make it unique in the machine).

Dean